# Swift: how to pass a value received from delegate to a function's completion block?

Tags: swift, closures, avfoundation, completionhandler

I am trying to capture an image with AVFoundation in Swift 4.2
The capture function lives inside a CameraEngine class that serves basically to setup the camera. So that in my VC, I can just do cameraEngine.setup() and everything is done for us.
Here's the capture function:

```
class CameraEngine: NSObject {

private var capturedImageData: Data?
...

    func captureImage() {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        print(capturedImageData)
    }

...

}
extension CameraEngine: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        self.capturedImageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I pass the value received by the delegate to the function and back to the VC via completion handler?

And called on my VC like this
`cameraEngine.captureImage()`

I was hoping to get the data back so that I can manipulate it from my VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a completion block as parameter to the `captureImage` method. Assign it to the `completion` parameter of the `CameraEngine` engine class. When the `photoOutput` is received you can just use this completion block. Here's how:

```
class CameraEngine: NSObject {

    private var capturedImageData: Data?
    //...
    var completion: ((Data?) -> Void)?
    func captureImage(completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        //...
    }
    //...
}
extension CameraEngine: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        completion?(photo.fileDataRepresentation())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let cameraEngine = CameraEngine()
cameraEngine.captureImage { data in
    print(data)
}
```